# "Fullscreen" popup in another popup

Tags: javascript, popup

is there any way to open popup in another popup? The second popup shuld cover or fill whole first popup. I wonder what should be written in heigth and width places.

```
.dialog({
        height: 550,
        width: 1150,
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

z-index is the level of layout, if you want to put something in front of others you should change his z-index, bigger than others

```
.dialog({
        height: 100%,
        width: 100%,
        z-index: 10,
    });
```

Comment: In javascript is `document.getElementById("yourElement").style.zIndex = "10"`